# Different methods for finding angle between two vectors

Tags: c++, 2d

Last year I learnt at a school, in a C++ game dev class, that to find the angle between two vectors you could use this method:

vec2_t is defined as: `typedef float vec2_t[2];`
vec[0] = x and vec[1] = y

```
float VectorAngle(vec2_t a, vec2_t b)
{
    vec2_t vUp;
    vec2_t vRight;
    vec2_t vDir;
    float dot, side, angle;

    VectorCopy(vUp, a);
    VectorNormalize(vUp);

    VectorInit(vRight, -vUp[1], vUp[0]);

    VectorCopy(vDir, b);
    VectorNormalize(vDir);

    dot = VectorDot(vUp, vDir);
    side = VectorDot(vRight, vDir);
    angle = acosf(dot);

    if(side < 0.0f)
        angle *= -1.0f;

    return angle;
}
```

Then just yesterday while looking for a solution to something else I found you could use this method instead:

```
float VectorAngle(vec2_t a, vec2_t b)
{
    return atan2f(b[1]-a[1], b[0]-a[0]);
}
```

This seems much more simple to implement... my question is, why would one favour one method over the second one when the second one is much more simple?

EDIT: Just to make sure:
If vector a is [100, 100] and vector b is [300, 300] then method 2 returns 0.78539819 radians, is this correct?

Comment: Does method 2 actually give the right answer? It seems to me that it does not.

Comment: I'm using it now and it seems like it does.

Comment: the angle between (100, 100) and (300, 300) is 0, because they are pointing in exactly the same direction.

Comment: That's weird because when I create a vector that is [0.78539819*dist[0], 0.78539819*dist[1]] and use that as a velocity it the object that started at (100, 100) goes in the direction towards the object at (300, 300) (dist is the distance between (100,100) and (300,300))

Comment: The second is certainly incorrect.  Consider vectors (9999, 1) and (10000, 2).  Using the second method you would get atan2(1, 1) which is 0.785398 radians (45 degrees).  The angle between those vectors is obviously not 45 degrees.

Answer (score 3):

A method I find usable:

```
        // cross product
        double y = (v1[0] * v2[1]) - (v2[0] * v1[1]);

        // dot product
        double x = (v1[0] * v2[0]) + (v1[1] * v2[1]);

        return atan2(y, x);
```

Answer (score 2):

The second method calculates the geometric difference vector for b and a (b-a) and returns the angle between this difference and X axis, Obviously such angle is not generelly equal to angle between a and b.

Answer (score 1):

Compare the [acosf](http://www.publicsource.apple.com/source/Libm/Libm-315/Source/ARM/acosf.c) source to [atanf2f](http://svn.open64.net/svnroot/open64/trunk/osprey/libacml_mv/src/atan2f.c) source to see difference in implementations. The latter uses a table which might be infeasible for some systems.

Answer (score 0):

You can use complex numbers for 2d vector calculations. Multiplication of complex numbers can be seen as a positive rotation, and division as a negative rotation. We want to use division as it acts to subtract one angle from the other:

```
#include <complex>

int main() {
    using std::complex;
    using std::arg;

    complex<double> a, b;

    double angle = arg(a/b);

    return 0;
}
```